# OpenGL texture array initialization

Tags: opengl

I want to use texture arrays to reduce the high texture binding cost, but I can't upload the data to the texture array. I use Tao framework. Here's my code:

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT);
Gl.glGenTextures(1, out textureArray);
Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, textureArray);

var data = new uint[textureWidth, textureHeight, textureCount];
for (var x = 0; x < textureWidth; x++)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < textureHeight; y++)
    {
        for (var z = 0; z < textureCount; z++)
            data[x, y, z] = GetRGBAColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}

Gl.glTexImage3D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, textureWidth, 
    textureHeight, textureCount, 0, Gl.GL_RGBA, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

Console.WriteLine(Glu.gluErrorString(Gl.glGetError()));
```

The glTexImage3D function says there is an invalid enumerant.

Comment: Are you sure that `glTexImage3D()` actually generates the error? The above code just schecks if _any_ GL call before that generates an error. Also, have you checked that your implementation actually supports the `GL_EXT_texture_array` extension?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I checked GL_EXT_texture_array, it is supported. As I see the invalid enumerant error was generated by the Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT); I thought it writes out the error of the last command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause for a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` in the above code is the

```
Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT);
```

call.

This is simply not allowed. Array textures cannot be used with the fixed-function pipeline, but only with shaders (which do not need those texture enables at all). The [`GL_EXT_texture_array` spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt) makes this quite clear:

> This extension does not provide for the use of array textures with fixed-function fragment processing.  Such support could be added by providing an additional extension allowing pplications to pass the new target enumerants (TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY_EXT and TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT) to Enable and Disable.

There never was any further extension allowing array textures for fixed-function processing (AFAIK)...

Comment: I use shaders, but there is only black color, when I get the color from the texture, but it seems now it's not related to the invalid enumerant error

Comment: @KocsisDávid: I think you should post another question, showing your shaders and shader/uniform setup code. There is no chance to guess what the problem might be without that information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2nd parameter of glTexImage3d into 1.

I don't know why, however, nvidia's opengl driver seems to need at least 1 level for texture 2d array object.